# how to open web browser control in IE 8

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, webbrowser-control, regedit

i am trying to use web browser control in my windows form application.

By default the web browser renders in **IE 7** mode.i need to run the application in at least **IE 8** but not in compatibility mode, by default the web browser of **.Net framework 4** opens in Compatibility mode.

After some search i found that i need to add a key in my regedit. where i have to specify the application name and the required IE version.

I tried this but is not working

```
    var IEVAlue = 8888; // for ie8
    var targetApplication = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe";
    var keyName = "FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";
    RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
   myKey.SetValue(keyName, IEVAlue, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're chaning the key in **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE** or **HKEY_CURRENT_USER**.
But it might be important to know if you're running 64-bit or 32 bit.

Under the software node in the registry, there's a node **Wow6432**, and under that, you also have **'\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl'**.

Can you try changing the value in there and see if it's working?